# Trying to get wxButton to resize on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets on Mac:
I have the following code:

```
    bool myApp::OnInit()
{
       wxFrame *myFrame = new wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "My App", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(1920, 1080));
    myFrame->Show(true);

    wxBoxSizer *mySizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    myFrame->SetSizer(mySizer);

    wxButton *my_button = new wxButton(myFrame, wxID_ANY, "TEST");
    my_button->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(66, 0, 0));
    mySizer->Add(my_button, 1, wxEXPAND);

    myFrame->Layout();
    return true;
}
```

I cant understand why the button does not resize.
Could anyone help? thanks

EDIT: I have just discovered that if i manually resize the window, then the button jumps from top left to being stretched horizontally, but only entered vertically. Still dont know why it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: you should call `Layout()` after you done with setting all your controls in a sizers.

Comment: BTW, if you have only one button it should fill up the whole space (after the `Layout()` call, of course).

Comment: Thank you for that. When I add the Layout() then the button is stretched horizontally and cantered vertically as soon as the program starts. But should it expand vertically too?

Comment: yes it should. Check my second comment.

Comment: Ok, but its still not doing that. Just stretching horizontally, but only centered vertically.

Comment: On further investigation; the button object is actually being resized to fill the vertical space, but it is not drawn to appear to fill the space. How can I get it to visually fill the space?

Comment: can you make a screenshot? And place it in line in the OP?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by OP?

Comment: it means `original posting `.

Comment: this screenshot is taken after the call to `Layout()`, correct? Also, Itry to create and add button to a sizer first, then call `SetSizer()`, just like in many samples provided...

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. I've noticed that the whole area functions as a button, but it is just not drawn that way.

Comment: weird. what is your GTK+ versuion? Are you running X or Wayland?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to wxWidgets and don't know to what you refer. I am on mac.

Comment: can you update the code in the OP with your current one? Also, what OSX version you are on? And what exact wx version?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the OP, I am on MAC Monterey 12.6.3, WxWidgets 3.2.2

Comment: you code is still not the current one. Please call `SetSizer()` and then `Layout()` and then it should work. Please check the code in a different samples provided with the library (they should be in the `samples` directory of the distribution)

Comment: Also - call to the `Show()` should be the last one in the constructor. Otherwise it could flicker.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get something that works, but is not perfect. If you assign a bitmap, the button does expand to fill the surroundings, so the one I use is sized 1x1.

Also, if you change the button text, it reverts to standard size.

```
bool myApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *myFrame = new wxFrame(this, wxID_ANY, "My App", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 800));

    myFrame->Show(true);

    wxBoxSizer *mySizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    myFrame->SetSizer(mySizer);

    wxButton *my_button1 = new wxButton(myFrame, wxID_ANY, "\nTEST1\n");

    wxBitmap changedBMP(wxSize(1, 1));// = wxNullBitmap;// = unchangedBitmap;
    wxMemoryDC memDC;
    memDC.SelectObject(changedBMP);

    wxColour bgcolour = wxSystemSettings::GetColour(wxSYS_COLOUR_BTNFACE);//m_colourDefaultBackground;

    memDC.SetBackground(bgcolour);
    memDC.Clear();
    memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
    
    my_button1->SetBitmap(changedBMP);
    mySizer->Add(my_button1, 1, wxEXPAND);

    myFrame->Layout();
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that code is not flickering. You call `Layout()` at the end after the `Show()`, which means all controls will be jumping into their positions and it will be visible. Check the code I posted and check the widgets sample in your wxWidgwets distribution.

Comment: Have you tried your code on the Mac?

Comment: what did it do for you? WHat OSX are you trying to run it on? And what wxWidgets version? Can you build and run widgets sample successfully? Or any other sample for that matter?

Comment: I've been using wxWidgets for years (my current build is version 3.1.5).

Running Sonoma (but I see the same behaviour on Ventura as well).

As the original poster said, you get a button, but it does not fill the area. But if you add a bitmap to it, the button does size correctly.

Comment: I've been using it also for a long time. The code I posted should work correctly and it doesn't need any bitmaps. But now I'm curious what does it do for you?

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below. It should work.

As I mentioned previously - you need to look at the different samples and the documentation in order to get a hold of how to work with wxWidgets.

```
bool myApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *myFrame = new wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "My App", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(1920, 1080));

    wxBoxSizer *mySizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    wxButton *my_button = new wxButton(myFrame, wxID_ANY, "TEST");
    my_button->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(66, 0, 0));
    mySizer->Add(my_button, 1, wxEXPAND);

    myFrame->SetSizer(mySizer);
    myFrame->Layout();
    myFrame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

BTW, the code you posted is also incorrect - check what I changed in you sample and use that to make a real program.